# How transform geometry column using GeoDjango

Tags: django, geospatial, django-queryset, geodjango

I am trying to transform geometry column in django, here is my model

```
class Network(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    geometry = models.GeometryField(srid=3857, null=True, blank=True)
    bbox = models.GeometryField(srid=3857, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tbl_network'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
```

I am trying to transform **bbox** column but `GeoQuerySet` automatically tranforms **geometry** column

```
Network.objects.transform(srid=3857).values('geometry','bbox')
```

**SQL query output of above django query**

```
  SELECT ST_Transform("tbl_network"."geometry", 3857), "tbl_network"."bbox" FROM "tbl_network"
```

So i tried it different way, now I exclude **geometry** column

```
 Network.objects.transform(srid=3857).values('bbox')
```

**SQL query output of above django query**

```
 SELECT "tbl_network"."bbox" FROM "tbl_network"
```

Now `GeoQuerySet` totally ignores the transform function.

So my questions is: how can i transform specific column of model?

**I got reply from this django forum but i cannot understand what is the issue with multiple geometry column**

> "I see so the 1st query works and the 2nd one fails to do the
>   transform.  I think the problem may be related to you having 2
>   geometry columns in  the same Postgis table.
>
> Are both of them listed in the geometry_columns view of Postgis. 
>   Typically only 1 can be the default. In this case geometry, so 
>   Geodjango/Postgis is recognizing it as a spatial column. But when it 
>   get's to bbox it doesn't recognize it and doesn't know what the FROM 
>   (current) srid is so a Transform wouldn't work.
>
> One option would be to return the data and then transform it once you 
>   have the spatial objects into python variables. "

Can anyone explain this reply?

Answer (score 3):

In your model, you have two Geometry Fields: `geometry` and `bbox`. Most methods for geometry fields (such as transform) use one of the fields as default. Calling the method will then only affect that specific field, and the second geometry field will remain unchanged.

To transform both geometries, you have to call the transform method twice, once for each field. You can specify the filed using the `field_name` parameter as described in the [django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#geoqueryset-methods).

With your model, you could do the following:

```
# Get network models
queryset = Network.objects.all()

# Transform geometry field
queryset = queryset.transform(3857, field_name='geometry')

# Transform bbox field
queryset = queryset.transform(3857, field_name='bbox')
```

Also, from reading your example I am wondering if the `bbox` field you use represents the bounding box of the `geometry` field. If that is the case, you are storing redundant information and you could remove the `bbox` field. Simply use the [GEOSGEometry extent property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.extent) to get the bounding box of your geometry, then you also only have to transform the main geometry:

```
# Network model with only one geometry field
class Network(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    geometry = models.GeometryField(srid=3857, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

and then

```
# Transform geometry field (which is the default if there is only one geom field)
queryset = Network.objects.all().tansform(3857)

# Bbox coordinates of first geometry in new coordinates
ntwork = queryset[0]
bbox = ntwork.geometry.extent
```